# Android Canvas draw out values from large ArrayList

Tags: android, draw, android-canvas

I have a big arraylist with 300 odd longitude/latitude pixel coordinates to draw onto my canvas. I have it working by iterating over the arraylist and calling drawCircle() on each lat/lon value.. Since I have 300 odd lon/lats I was wondering is there any easier way that requires less processing? Like instead of drawing each individual circle out...can I draw lines connecting every so often lat/lon values??